# Keycloak invalid_grant with Authorization Grant flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

So this is what I did,
I have a Keycloak server running on `localhost:8080` and I have configured a public client called `myclient` inside a realm `myrealm`.
I have added a response_url address as `http://localhost:3000/*`
I invoke a code request using this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code
```

I am challenged for a login and then after successful login I login get a callback something like this. which obviously gives me a Not found as I don't have anything running on 3000 Port.

```
http://localhost:3000/?session_state=6af80f75-19b0-4c65-8d8b-89ca1cf5fd0d&code=e2082b9d-4199-4f0e-a3de-d9216ab70ac5.6af80f75-19b0-4c65-8d8b-89ca1cf5fd0d.8fa6724d-ffd2-4bb4-9ed9-7302acb432e8
```

I pick the code from above and then make a curl call below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=e2082b9d-4199-4f0e-a3de-d9216ab70ac5.6af80f75-19b0-4c65-8d8b-89ca1cf5fd0d.8fa6724d-ffd2-4bb4-9ed9-7302acb432e8&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&client_id=myclient" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

I get an error saying

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}
```

when I try the same thing with https://www.keycloak.org/app/ it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does scope need to include `offline_access`?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the code is already used for access token retrieval once. Try with new authorization code